# Does Amazon provide S3DistCp java api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop2

I want to integrate s3 to hadoop file transfer in Java Code. Does Amazon provide any API for this task. I want to use S3DistCp.

Comment: To learn what APIs are exposed in AWS SDk For Java v2 -- refer to the Javadocs.  https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html

Answer (score 1):

not AFAIK, but you can use the apache one, it's in the `org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-distcp` module. I use it in tests (more specifically, the Hadoop azure & s3a clients use it to verify that distcp works with their object stores).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java de-compiler to see the source code and the implementation by using the s3distcp.jar. This can be downloaded from this following location.

```
s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.latest/s3distcp.jar
```

Comment: Decompiling jars won't really help in searching for API: since there is no mention of which parts of the JAR you decompiled are considered API (and have some consistency guarantees that you would expect from one), or are they just some internal implementation details that might get changed at any time without prior notice and break your app.

Comment: Yes @M.Prokhorov  You are correct but in this case there is no direct API except the distcp from apache. So in that case decompiler can be little bit helpful.